# Maui, xamarin: Application.Current.UserAppTheme Always returns "unspecified"

Tags: xamarin, maui

I am trying to react to theme changes in my app; i have this handler:

```
private void OnThemeChanged()
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        if (Application.Current.UserAppTheme == AppTheme.Dark)
        {
            lbl_email.TextColor = Colors.Gray;
            lbl_appversion.TextColor = Colors.Gray;
        }
        else if (Application.Current.UserAppTheme == AppTheme.Light)
        {
            lbl_email.TextColor = Colors.Blue;
            lbl_appversion.TextColor = Colors.Blue;
        }
        else if (Application.Current.UserAppTheme == AppTheme.Unspecified)
        {
            lbl_email.TextColor = Colors.Yellow;
            lbl_appversion.TextColor = Colors.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_email.TextColor = Colors.Green;
            lbl_appversion.TextColor = Colors.Green;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    });

}
```

unfortunately, the texts ALWAYS change their color to yellow as my app theme is always returned as unspecified.

What could be of issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Requested Theme instead works:

```
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        if(Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark)
        {
            lbl_email.TextColor = Colors.White;
            lbl_appversion.TextColor = Colors.White;
        }
        if (Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Light)
        {
            lbl_email.TextColor = Colors.Black;
            lbl_appversion.TextColor = Colors.Black;
        }        
        OnPropertyChanged();
    });
```

Comment: Excellent! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.